# Sourcefile name change in SSIS Package

Tags: ssis

I have created SSIS packages which imports Excel files from a folder. The name of the Excel file changes based on months.
e.g.: I:\Test\User_09-05-2016.xlsx or 
      I:\Test\User_09-06-2016.xlsx etc.....

I want to create SQL jobs to run the packages because I will get a new file every month.
I want to archive the excel file after successful package execution(to keep only one excel file in folder at a time).

How can I automate the process?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a ForEach container within SSIS.

Import each spreadsheet within that folder.

Delete (or move) each spreadsheet after processing.

Comment: How can a package handle if source file name changed from I:\Test\User_09-05-2016.xlsx to I:\Test\User_09-06-2016.xlsx

Comment: Just use a ForEach container within SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach to FE loop - define path and filename of Excel file on the package run.
If you know rules for naming Excel files, create a string variable *Excel_FilePath* containing complete path with Expression like `[User::Folder Path]+"\\"+[User::Filename]+".xlsx"`. Then take your Excel file Connection Manager and add the following expression to the ConnectionString property `"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + @[User::Excel_FilePath] + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES\";"`
In Package properties - set *DelayValidation=true*.
More [details on this approach with screenshots](http://bi-polar23.blogspot.ru/2007/08/loading-multiple-excel-files-with-ssis.html) and [exactly your question reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231486/how-do-i-set-up-a-dynamic-file-path-in-ssis-for-an-excel-file).

Comment: Thanks for your replay.... I have gone through with the screen shots which you provided. But i don't want to extract data from multiple files. I need to pull the data from single excel file which is having different file names (dates) for every month.

Comment: In the article author wants to process multiple files. In your case - do not use Loops and create ConnectionManager string as described. Another approach - create your package processing single Excel file and pass adjusted *ConnectionString* when your are calling this package from SQL Job. But in this case you have to dynamically create connection string in SQL Job, which can be tricky.